# Suppose $X,Y$ are independent and $X\sim N(1,4)$ and $Y\sim N(1,9)$. If $P(2X+Y\le a)=P(4X−2Y\ge 4a)$, then find $a$.

Tags: probability

Suppose $X,Y$ are independent and $X\sim N(1,4)$ and $Y\sim N(1,9)$. If $P(2X+Y\le a)=P(4X−2Y\ge 4a)$, then find $a$.

Comment: can someone give me hint to solve this question

Comment: Find the distribution of $2X+Y$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Did you try anything?

Comment: i don't try any nothing because i don't understand the question

Comment: What don't you understand about the question?

Answer (score 3):

Recall if $X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$,$Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ and $X,Y$ are independent then $AX+BY \sim N(A \mu_X + B  \mu_Y, A^2 \sigma_X^2+B^2 \sigma_Y^2)$. 
Then manipulate and use the symmetrical properties of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Normalize the distribution to make it $N(0,1)$.
- If $X$ is a normal distributions with mean $0$. If $P(X > b)=P(X<c)$, then $b=-c$.